# How to remove a random number from a specific location withing a string

Tags: mysql

I honestly don't know if this is possible, but I'm trying to remove random number that are in specific locations withing my data.  Basically I have

```
4586146,
4586126,
4582422,
4582482
```

I need to remove only the 4th number, and leave the rest.

Comment: You mean the 4th digit, so `4586146` becomes `458146`?

Comment: The fourth number 4582482? Or the fourth digit (eg. 6 in 4586146)?

Answer (score 2):

Just use string functions:

```
select concat(left(col, 3), substr(col, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(num, 1, 3), SUBSTR(num, 5)) AS new_num
FROM YourTable
```

MySQL will automatically convert a number to a string when using a string function such as `SUBSTR`. And if you use this in an `UPDATE` statement, it will convert it back to a number when storing it.